# Couchbase implementation language

Tags: database, nosql, couchbase

What is the implementation language of Couchbase? I have found some pages that states that it is: C, C++, Go and Erlang... but it does not make sense to be implemented in C++, Go and Erlang at the same time.

On their GitHub I couldn't find the source code of their database server, but it is stated that it's open source...

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Couchbase Server consists of several modules, and there is no single source repository of it. You can find list of projects here: https://github.com/couchbase/manifest

Also keep in mind that Enterprise Edition contains parts which are closed, and their not available for download.

For example, current master version (where active development goes) described by this file: https://github.com/couchbase/manifest/blob/master/branch-master.xml, and contains modules written in C, C++, Go, Erlang and Java. And it is totally makes sense to use different programming languages to write single project.

Comment: Thank you, but where can I find those modules?

Comment: Have a look in the XML files in that manifest.  For instance, in 4.6.4: https://github.com/couchbase/manifest/blob/master/couchbase-server/watson/4.6.4.xml I see github.com/couchbase/cbft and https://github.com/couchbase/cbgt and https://github.com/couchbase/goxdcr etc. Any particular module you are looking for?